# filter_input textarea not working

Tags: php, filter-input

I am new using filter_input. At least it works fine with normal form fields however when I try with a text area then it returns false.

Textarea:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
```

Below here you see the code I use.

```
filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, "message", FILTER_DEFAULT);
```

This returns:

```
filter_input or filter_input_array = bool(false);
$_POST["message"] = "message";
```

However if I just use `$_POST["message"]` it works fine. But here I get a warning from netbeans. So I'de like to use another way to get it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what does and doesn't work with exact code usage?

Comment: well filter_input returns false and $_POST["message"] returns the content

Comment: what are you putting in to `filter_input`?

Comment: text area where the name is "message". input fields like text and others works fine but the text area doesn't work.

Comment: @Lennard It works fine with `filter_input(INPUT_POST, "message", FILTER_DEFAULT);`

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. Now it work fines yes. Don't know what happened thought. Thanks  @Malik  for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "message", FILTER_DEFAULT);
    echo $message;
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

To know more about PHP Filter visit [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filter.asp)